# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable with my_curser.fetchone()[1] in mysql under a function while using python with tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, tkinter

the code runs properly without a function but when i put it under a function like this then it doesn't work and throws error
I googled for solution but it didn't worked so your help will be amazing for a beginner like me

```
def updatedetails():
   
    getpid = str(search_box.get())

    my_cursor.execute("SELECT * from patient_tbll where PID = '"+getpid+"'")
    output=my_cursor.fetchone()[1]
    print(output)
```

Error on `my_cursor.fetchone()[1]` :

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `fetchone()` will return `None` if no row is returned from the database.  You need to check that a row has been returned before trying to extract its elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be making queries like this as it allows injection without proper sanitisation.

I suggest you look at the documentation for the MySQL lib you are using as some may differ

e.g. MySQL.connector

```
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_no = %(emp_no)s"
cursor.execute(select_stmt, { 'emp_no': 2 })
```

or

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = %s"
adr = ("Yellow Garden 2", )

cursor.execute(sql, adr)
```

fetchone() will return a tuple, try:

```
output=my_cursor.fetchone()
print(output[1])
```

print(output) to see the actual returned cursor.